# Upload file to Drive and set file name

Tags: c++, google-drive-api, libcurl

I want to upload a file to Google Drive and set its name as I understood I have to use `uploadType=multipart`

I am under c++ and using cURL lib.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a multipart request with metadata and media parts. Use `curl_formadd` and make sure your request looks like:

```
POST /upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: your_auth_token
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="boundary_tag"

--boundary_tag
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "title": "My title"
}

--boundary_tag
Content-Type: image/jpeg

data

--boundary_tag--
```