# Upload to google drive using cURL and set name and location

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I'm attempting to upload a file to Google Drive using cURL.  The files get uploaded, but, only in the root and are always named "Untitled".

My base script looks like this:

```
curl 
    --silent 
    --request POST 
    --data-binary "@c:\temp\myfile.jpg"         
    -H "Authorization: Bearer abcdefg" 
    -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media"
```

Using these links as references:

[Upload file to Drive and set file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685624/upload-file-to-drive-and-set-file-name)

https://gist.github.com/deanet/3427090

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads

I note that this might be required, which is defined on Google's documentation (see link)

```
-H "Slug: myfile3.jpg"
```

But this has no effect whether or not I put it in.

Using cURL help, I note this might be helpful:

```
 -OL MyFolder\myfile2.jpeg
```

...but this has no effect, either.

I also note that the string {title:file title} may be required, but I don't know how to embed it in using cURL.  Based on the above links, I thought I could just append it at the end of one of the headers, just before the body.  So, I tried to get clever and changed the content-type specification to this:

```
-H "Content-Type: image/jpeg {"title":"myfile4"}"
```

...but it also has no effect.

Curiously, Google's own documentation is incorrect, so, I suspect that the method they once used is now out of date.  The authorization specification in the link is wrong.  You must use Bearer tokens, not "GoogleLogin".  I referred to this link:

https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL

My entire script looked like this.  It uploads, but, not where I want it and not named the way I want it.

```
curl 
    --silent 
    --request POST 
    --data-binary "@c:\temp\myfile.jpg"         
    -OL MyFolder\myfile2.jpeg
    -H "Slug: myfile3.jpg" 
    -H "Authorization: Bearer abcdefg" 
    -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg {"title":"myfile4"}" 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media"
```

I realize I specified "myfile2.jpg" in one place, "myfile3.jpg" in another, and "myfile4" in yet another.  It makes no difference whether they are matched or specified at all.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing the media content without the meta data. You have two ways forward :-

1. POST the metadata to create the empty file and capture its file-id. Then use the file-id for a content upload
2. Create a multipart mime body which contains both the metadata and content in a single POST

Personally, I'd go with option 1 as it separates out the two concerns, but both are equally valid. The options are described at https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads

Comment: but option #1 wouldnt require more roundtrips and a chance to leave a half baked file if the server somehow fails to make the 2nd post? why do you prefer option 1?

Comment: There is no such thing as a half baked file in Google Drive. It either does or does not exist and it either does or does not have content. With option 1, if the second post fails, you simply retry it. If you go with a multipart upload, there is nothing in the Drive API spec that confirms that this is dealt with as a single atomic operation. It probably is, but if it's not in the spec then you run the risk of tripping up over a bug or a behaviour change. The other reason for going with option 1 is that you can easily upgrade your code to do resumable or chunked uploads.

Comment: cool. my only remaining picky comment is that i do think the file can be half baked. by that i mean a file with metadata but no content. the server cant always retry because may not even have received/saved the returned file id (say it crashes or loses connection just in between steps) while that would de dealt better by drive in case 2

Comment: files with no content are relatively commonplace in Drive. A folder is a contentless file with a specific mime type, as is a shortcut. Apps can have all kinds of proprietary reasons to create content-less files such as an app-specific tagging mechanism (think folders but without the bizarre cascading delete). A server crash leaves an equally indeterminate situation in both cases. For all but very small files, it is recommended to do resumable or chunked uploads, which is a variant of option 1. I haven't tested it, but I suspect that option 1 also provides better throughput for bulk uploads

Comment: In the link, it says there are two ways, a simple way and a multipart.  In the simple way, a response is returned via JSON which indicates the title - but doesn't say how it's specified in the request.  In the multipart way, the title is embedded in the body, but doesn't give an example of how to do this (I'm using cURL).  The metadata returned in the response includes the title (ostensibly, the one set in the request).  How would I specify the title in either method?

Comment: you should read the link I pasted in conjunction with the api description of files.insert

Comment: Thank you for trying.  But clearly I'm not getting it.  Nothing in any of the links, or the files.insert details, describe how cURL can be used to upload a file, to a location, with a custom name.

Comment: Adopt my option 1. The first post has a simple body of {title:My Title}. Capture the returned json and v extract the Id. Then use that id in a put to the upload url.