# What is the proper format of a curl POST request to upload a file to Google Drive (using Drive REST API v3)?

Tags: bash, curl, google-drive-api

In Google's documentation for the Drive REST API v3, they provide the following "example" for how to upload a file to Drive using the "simple upload" method:

`POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
JPEG data`

I am trying to construct a curl POST request to upload a .csv to Drive. I have tried the following (as well as countless variations), with no success. It keeps returning with an `Error 400 (bad request)!!!` error:

`curl -s "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1" -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" -H "Content-Type: $mime_type" -H "Content-Length: $file_size" -d "$file" -X POST`

For reference, the variables are defined as:

`file_size="$(du -b $file | awk '{ print $1 }')"`

`mime_type=$(file -ib "$file")`

Anyway, Google doesn't explain the "JPEG data" part, and I suspect that is where my curl POST request is wrong.

I've found a bunch of relevant examples on both here and Github, but none of them worked for me (all of the ones I found were outdated, anyway). I also tried multipart uploading, but I also couldn't get that to work (and again, most of the examples here seemed outdated).

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304455/upload-to-google-drive-using-curl-and-set-name-and-location (or this could be beneficial for your case, as well)

Comment: That is for v2 of the Drive REST API. I specifically asked about v3. There are significant differences between the versions. It is a similar question, but I don't think it's technically a dupe. Thank you, though. I had already seen this, and tried the suggestions. I can't even get the metadata to POST (400 bad request error), as suggested by pinoyyid in their answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping @pinoyyid's answer could shed some light in to your issue (referenced article was for v3 as well).

Comment: It is, but Google doesn't elaborate on what `JPEG data` should look like. I assume it's JSON-formatted, something like: `-H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ "title": "DATA TEST" }"` but I'm not sure, since I keep receiving a `bad request` error.

For v2, Google provides a UI to test out requests, and then it provides you with the correct formatting. It's under "Try it out" on some of the Drive REST API documentation pages. I found it helpful in the past, but I can't seem to find something similar for v3.

Comment: it's simply binary data, unless you've explicitly set a content-encoding header, eg to base64

Comment: That's what I thought. Either Google's documentation is incorrect (which is possible) or I'm just misunderstanding it (also possible). Do I have to supply a header when specifying the file/data to be uploaded? I've seen `-H Slug:` or something along those lines for insert requests using v2 API (in GitHub gists from 2012), but that doesn't seem to work for v3 (and tbh, I couldn't get that to work with v2 either).